# Double Linked List header node keeps returning first value as 0

Tags: c++

I will preface to say that this is my first question.  I am currently getting my Masters degree in Information Security and I had to take C++ programming this semester.  So this is homework related.  I am not looking for you to answer my homework but I am running into a peculiar situation. I have created the program to work with a doubly linked list and everything works fine.  However when I have the user create a list of values the first node keeps returning 0.  I have tried finding some reading on this and I cannot locate any reference to it.  My question is then is the header node(first node) always going to be zero?  Or am I doing something wrong.

```
case: 'C':
 cout<<"Please enter a list:"<<endl;
  while(n!=-999){
     myList.insert(n);
     cin>> n;}
  break;
```

I now enter:  12321, 1234,64564,346346.  The results in 0, 12321, 1234, 64564,346346.  Is this what should happen or am I doing something wrong?  Also as this is my first post please feel free to criticize or teach me how to color code the keywords.

Anyway this is a homework assignment so I am only looking for guidance and constructive criticism.

Thank you all in advance

So I cannot figure out the comment sections on this forum so I will edit the original post
The first section is the constructor code:

```
template <class Type>
 doublyLinkedList<Type>::doublyLinkedList()
  {
    first= NULL;
    last = NULL;
    count = 0;
      }
```

Then there is my insert function :

```
template <class Type>
void doublyLinkedList<Type>::insert(const Type& insertItem)
 {
nodeType<Type> *current;      //pointer to traverse the list
nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent; //pointer just before current
nodeType<Type> *newNode;      //pointer to create a node
bool found;

newNode = new nodeType<Type>; //create the node
newNode->info = insertItem;  //store the new item in the node
newNode->next = NULL;
newNode->back = NULL;

if(first == NULL) //if the list is empty, newNode is 
                  //the only node
{
   first = newNode;
   last = newNode;
   count++;
}
else
{
    found = false;
    current = first;

    while (current != NULL && !found) //search the list
        if (current->info >= insertItem)
            found = true;
        else
        {
            trailCurrent = current;
            current = current->next;
        }

    if (current == first) //insert newNode before first
    {
        first->back = newNode;
        newNode->next = first;
        first = newNode;
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
          //insert newNode between trailCurrent and current
        if (current != NULL)
        {
            trailCurrent->next = newNode;
            newNode->back = trailCurrent;
            newNode->next = current;
            current->back = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            trailCurrent->next = newNode;
            newNode->back = trailCurrent;
            last = newNode;
        }

        count++;
      }//end else
   }//end else
}//end
```

Then I have an initialization function too:

```
template <class Type>
 void doublyLinkedList<Type>::initializeList()
 {
  destroy();
}
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Yeah, the coloration is neat, isn't it!  Anyway, please also post your doubly linked list code.  The problem might be there.

Comment: I believe @maniek got it. What is `n` before first insert?

Comment: 'code'
template<class Type>
doublyLinkedList<Type>::doublyLinkedList()

Comment: @Craig: When the help says to write "\`code\`", those are _backticks_ not single quotes, and "code" should be replaced by your actual code. That is, to get code formatting, surround it with backticks. Example: Write \`my code here\` to get `my code here`

Comment: Also I'm sorry but I can't help but point out that SO is not a forum.

Comment: @Craig take a look at maniek's answer, as I beieve it to be the right one. Step through the first entry of your loop in the VS debugger and pay close attention to the initial value of 'n' when it inserts before asking for the next one.

Comment: I see that.  I do apologize I did not mean to offend anyone by calling Stack Overflow a forum.  It is a great place where shared intelligence grows.  I have used the debugger and realized if I initialize first the issue goes away

Comment: The homework tag should not be used anymore, it's deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You insert first, then read the input.

Comment: @Craig: This is the correct answer. It identifies the logical error in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just by the content of your code, I believe maniek has the right answer, so kindly upvote him if/when you find the same, and not this answer please. This is for Craig to understand how to reorder his loop so it reads, tests, breaks if needed, else inserts.

```
while (cin >> n && n != 999)
    myList.insert(n);
```

There are about a dozen ways to code this, with a for-loop, do-while loop, etc, but that should get you running. Again, *please* consider up-voting maniek's answer if it solves your problem, and *please* mark the green check on it (and any other answers on StackOverflow that provide answers you're looking for).

Comment: I require 15 reputation before I can upvote the correct answer . How do I get more reputation because he is exactly right

Comment: You did enough by marking it green. Eventually you can upvote answers. You did it right. No worries.

Comment: Great.  I am glad i did this today.  I was stressing on this.  That is interesting on how you added the if statement in the Sentinel.  May I inquire as to why the switch was made.

Comment: nm. i'll try that again. You need something to test before the insert, and the bounds of your loop are either too early or too late. you *can* do it with different loop construct, but this introduces a single test condition, the others require two. For your needs this is probably the easiest to understand compared to the algorithm you're trying to code, which was the point for me putting here to begin with.

Comment: Ahhh this makes total sense. Simpler = more efficient.  I think that is what I got out of that

Comment: Heh. yeah, not always. Tell me that when you study recursion, often very simple to understand and code, and yet *tremendously* inefficient at the same time. Anyway. glad it helped.

Comment: I already studied recursion, and hate it, but I got an A of the recursion test so I guess I am doing alright.  Again thank you to everyone